# remove \n in html source code after appending to list

Tags: python, python-requests, newline

I am trying to implement get request to website, getting the html and appending it to a list. The problem is that it adds `\n` in random places, and I need to write a script to get rid of that problem. I have tried `strip()` and `replace()` and everything in between.

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.get(page)
data = r.text
html = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for lin in html.find_all("link", href=True):
    if "css" in lin['href']:
        urls.append(lin['href'])

for url in urls:
    if "http" in url:
        sourcecode.append(data)
```

I just need to eliminate `\n` from the source code.

Comment: What was the problem with "replace()"?

Comment: there is only one element in the list so I didn't think it would work but I tried for word in sourcecode: word.replace("\n"), this is the only way I could think of using it @MichaelButscher

Comment: Have you read the Python docs about "str.replace()"?

Answer (score 1):

I hope that resolve your problem. I checked it on some page and it worked.

```
r = requests.get(page)
data = r.text
html = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for lin in html.find_all("link", href=True):
    if "css" in lin['href']:
        urls.append(lin['href'].replace("\n", ""))

for url in urls:
    if "http" in url:
        sourcecode.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urls.append(lin['href'].replace("\n",""))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: didnt work, wouldnt make sense, \n has nothing to do with the urls

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by opening the file in binary mode!

f = open("file", "ab+")